# How can i insert a map using Google Maps Api V3 on adobe edge

Tags: google-maps-api-3, adobe-edge

I want to insert a map using google maps api.

I have set up a symbol and the "creationComplete" I have the following:

```
var map1 = sym $ ("MapBox.");
map1.html ('<div id="stage"> </ div>');


yepnope ({
load: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'
'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js'
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'
]
});

var options = {
zoom: 9
          center: new google.maps.LatLng (41.761997, -4.699409)
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          panControl: false,
          ZoomControl: false,
          ScaleControl: false,
          MapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
       };


var map2 = new google.maps.Map ($ ('# stage'), options);
```

But I do not load the map in the div. Does anyone know why?

Thank you very much for the help!